# Playing Sound With OpenAL

Tags: xcode, audio, iphone-sdk-3.0, openal, xcode3.2

Whats the best way to play a sound using OpenAL in xcode 3.2.2 on a 3.1.2 SDK
im pulling my brains out at the moment. I've followed ben brittel and mike daley's tutorials on openAL and ive implemented all the things needed to play sound. Basically i creaed a sound manager class with the help of their fantastic tutorials. 
The only problem is i get a SIGABRT error. the app doesnt even load when i try to initialise the sounds.
Im making a drum application. The app works fine until i try to play the sound

so ive decided i may need to start from fresh again. (since before i was playing sound using the playsystemsound but that is very slow and is not idea for games programming)
can someone please help and tell me the best way to play sound using OpenAL
Thanks
I need openal so i can use stuff like pitch control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Finch](https://github.com/zoul/Finch), a simple iOS SFX engine written atop of OpenAL. It has a very low latency, so that it should be a good fit for a drumming application, and it also offers pitch control.